# Three onClick actions on one button at same time

Tags: java, android, button, onclick

I develop a program that does when i click on a button that starts counting the clicks and show the count and after 5 seconds that button is desible and i want show countdown seconds too but it not showing

```
mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total_textview);
    mTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.count_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            final Button b = (Button)v;
            if (clicks == 0){
                // Means its the first time that a user click the button
                // Start a thread that is going to disable the button after 5 seconds from first click
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    b.setText("Time up");
                                    b.setEnabled(false);
                                    // Showing user clicks after button is disabled
                                    showClicks();
                                }
                            });
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }
            // Here we are just counting  . . . . including the first click
            countClicks();
        }
    });
}


private void countClicks(){
    ++clicks;
    mTextView.setText(Integer.toString(clicks));

    // You can update your text view here
}
private void showClicks(){
    mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(clicks)+"Clicks");
    mTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html).

Here your modified code which updates UI. It ticks ever 1 second and updates a TextView for 5 seconds. At the end, it says "Time up":

```
new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         b.setText("Seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         b.setText("Time up");
         b.setEnabled(false);
         // Showing user clicks after button is disabled
         showClicks();
     }
  }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this one some changes in your existing code:

```
mTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.total_textview);
        mTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

      button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.count_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                final Button b = (Button) v;
                if (clicks == 0) {
                    setCountDown();
                    // Means its the first time that a user click the button
                    // Start a thread that is going to disable the button after 5 seconds from first click
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(5000);
                                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        b.setText("Time up");
                                        b.setEnabled(false);
                                        // Showing user clicks after button is disabled
                                        showClicks();
                                    }
                                });
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();
                }
                // Here we are just counting  . . . . including the first click
                countClicks();
            }
        });





private void countClicks(){
        ++clicks;
        mTextView.setText(Integer.toString(clicks));

        // You can update your text view here
    }
    private void showClicks(){
        mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(clicks)+"Clicks");
        mTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }


    private void setCountDown(){
        t = new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                                  @Override
                                  public void run() {
                                      handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                                      handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                          public void run() {
                                              if (i > 0) {
                                                  button.setText("Time Left :" + Integer.toString(i--));
                                              } else {
                                                  t.cancel();
                                              }
                                          }
                                      });
                                  }

                              },
//Set how long before to start calling the TimerTask (in milliseconds)
                0,
//Set the amount of time between each execution (in milliseconds)
                1000);
    }
```

**int i=5 instance level**

**Timer t; //Java util Timer**

**Hanler handler;// Android OS handler**